# I am unable to configure email with my application i have created a separate email utility but following error is occurring

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to connect gmail server and want to send email to same account for learning purpose but it is throwing this exception.

```
@Service
public  class EmailUtilImpl implements EmailUtil {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @Override
    public void sendEmail(String toAddress, String subject, String body)
    {
        MimeMessage message= sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper= new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        try {
            helper.setTo(toAddress);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(body);
        }
        catch(MessagingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

---

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com 
spring.mail.port = 587 
spring.mail.username = myemail 
spring.mail.password = mypassword 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable= true         
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required = true # Other properties 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

**Error:**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Mail server connection failed; nested exception is
>   com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is:
>   java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect. Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is:
>   java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Comment: Please provide complete stacktrace.

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Comment: Hello @Springsecurity have you configured mail properties in the `application.properties`

Comment: @PatelRomil yes i have configured it please see in below comment.

Comment: @Springsecurity is mypassword  is generate using App Password https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try with below property

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: <YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
    password: <YOUR_EMAIL_PASSWORD>
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: true
          auth: true
```

Comment: this i have tried in application properties
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username = myemail
spring.mail.password = mypassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable= true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required = true

# Other properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000

Comment: Are you using right credentials ? it shows Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username= yourAccount@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= generated App Password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

[Generate App Password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

Other Possible Solutions

- Change Port to 465
- Disable your firewall/antivirus and run again
- Add java.net.preferIPv4Stack in the main application

  ```
  System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true")
  ```

Comment: spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactoy
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false

Comment: Above mentioned configuration worked for me thank for your effort Patel Romil @Yogesh Prajapati ..

Comment: not only port change is required but adding these two properties javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactoy ,fallback=false will work.

Comment: @Springsecurity I am glad that you have solved the issue